# Infinite loop when simulating a Program Counter design with Icarus Verilog

Tags: verilog, infinite-loop, program-counter, icarus

I am implementing a simple Program Counter adder with the following prototype:

```
module program_counter(input        enable_count,
                       input        enable_overwrite,
                       input[31:0]  overwrite_value,
                       output[31:0] out);
```

When simulating with Icarus Verilog, I get an infinite loop at the first tick on which overwriting is disabled and count is enabled, the internal register being therefore feeded by the output of the PC adder (PC + 4).

I simplified the issue to a basic piece of code with a D flip flop used as a 1-bit register:

```
module register(input in, input set, output out);

    wire not_in;
    wire q0;
    wire not_q0;
    wire not_q;

    nand (q0, in, set);

    not  (not_in, in);
    nand (not_q0, not_in, set);

    nand (out, q0, not_q);
    nand (not_q, not_q0, out);

endmodule

module test;

    reg  clock;
    reg  in;
    wire out;
    wire not_out;

    xor (x_out, out, 1);                // add
    or  (muxed_out, x_out, in);         // mux

    register r(muxed_out, clock, out);

    initial
    begin
        $dumpfile("test.vcd");
        $dumpvars(0, test);

        $display("\tclock,\tin,\tout");
        $monitor("\t%b,\t%x,\t%b",
                 clock, in, out);

        #0 assign in = 1;               // erase register
        #0 assign clock = 1;

        #1 assign in = 0;
        #1 assign clock = 0;

        #2 assign clock = 1;
        #3 assign clock = 0;
        #4 assign clock = 1;
    end

endmodule
```

The VCD output does not show any state change after the simulation gets stuck.

My guess is that, at a particular tick, the adder is constantly feeding a different value (continuously adding), so as it is not stable, the simulator is waiting the value to be fixed and gets stuck.

Is this design correct (i.e. can be synthesized and supposed to work) ?

Comment: Try to remove all of the `assign` key words in your code.

Comment: Noted ! I've tried to remove them, but it doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a combinational loop: The output of 'register' feeds back into its input through the xor/or gates in test. You've essentially created a [ring oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_oscillator).

If you add the following code inside register, you can see this happening:

```
  always @(in) $display("@%d: in = %d", $time, in);
```

You'll see a bunch of these when you run the interpreter:

```
@                   1: in = 1
@                   1: in = 0
@                   1: in = 1
@                   1: in = 0
```

It looks like you're trying to make an enabled latch in 'register'. Is that what you intended?  An edge triggered flip flop is the normal practice in synchronous design. You'd need two latches back-to-back to do that, but the standard (and much easier) way to do this in Verilog is like this:

```
reg my_flop;

always @(posedge clk)
   my_flop <= input;
```

If you really want a latch, it can be inferred like this (but these tend to be error prone and are generally discouraged):

```
always @(clk, input)
begin
    if (clk)
        my_flop = input;
end
```

Is there a reason you're trying to create these manually with gates?

Comment: Thank you ! Indeed, I have completely missed the fact that I didn't have an edge-triggered data flip-flop here but a simple data latch that is infinitely writing itself.

As for why I want to create this manually with gates, I felt like it was better to learn by being closer to the bare transistor and essentially write what the simulator would generate from an RTL description for instance.

I don't know if it makes sense.

Comment: I see. Note that an RTL simulator is generally going to model the flop as a unit rather than breaking it down further (even if you synthesized Verilog for an ASIC, it would map a flop to a single cell http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_cell)